# how to generate numbers in dataframe column in pandas?

Tags: python, dataframe

Suppose I have a=2; b=3. I want to use pandas dataframe in which my 1st and 2nd column should look like; The first column should print number upto 2 but the repetition should be 3. The second column should be a series from 1 to 3.

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

Please let me know the solution.

```py
import pandas as pd
d1=6
d2=8
for i in range(1,d1):
  for j in range(1,d2):
    pd.DataFrame((i,j),columns=['proteinA','proteinB']).to_csv('prediction_test_123.csv')
```

Please let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Pls use:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = 2
b = 3
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Column A': np.repeat(np.arange(1, a+1), b),
    'Column B': np.tile(np.arange(1, b+1), a)
})
print(df)
```

Another way:

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product

a = 2
b = 3

# cartesian product of the specified ranges
df = pd.DataFrame(list(product(range(1, a+1), range(1, b+1))), columns=['Column A', 'Column B'])
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Column A  Column B
0         1         1
1         1         2
2         1         3
3         2         1
4         2         2
5         2         3
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with lists, then convert to Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

myList = []
d1 = 6
d2 = 8
for i in range(d1):
    for j in range(d2):
        myList.append([i, j])
df = pd.DataFrame(myList, columns=['proteinA','proteinB'])

    proteinA  proteinB
0          0         0
1          0         1
2          0         2
3          0         3
4          0         4
5          0         5
6          0         6
7          0         7
8          1         0
9          1         1
10         1         2
11         1         3
12         1         4
13         1         5
14         1         6
15         1         7
16         2         0
17         2         1
18         2         2
19         2         3
20         2         4
21         2         5
22         2         6
23         2         7
24         3         0
25         3         1
26         3         2
27         3         3
28         3         4
29         3         5
30         3         6
31         3         7
32         4         0
33         4         1
34         4         2
35         4         3
36         4         4
37         4         5
38         4         6
39         4         7
40         5         0
41         5         1
42         5         2
43         5         3
44         5         4
45         5         5
46         5         6
47         5         7
```